# What is the carnatic equivalent taal name for Jhaptaal?

Tags: indian-classical

What is the name of the Taal in Carnatic music that is equivalent to [Jhaptaal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jhaptal)
in Hindustani music?

Answer (score 3):

Carnatic's *Kanda Chapu* Thaalam is the closest to Hindustani's Jhaptal. It's a 5 beat cycle, 2+3. Jhaptal is 10 beats with two 2+3 patterns. So, two cycles of Kanda Chapu will match a cycle of Jhaptal.

Thought it's possible to find a theoretically exact match Thaalam for Jhaptal, Khanda chapu is more popular and widely in use today. In fact, older carnatic compositions set to Jhampa Thaalam, a 10 beat cycle, are usually rendered in Kanda Chapu in concerts now-a-days.

If you want a theoretically accurate representation, then you need a thaalam with *drutam-laghu-drutam-laghu* pattern, should feature in the 108 thaala list, and use a trisra-jaati laghu (3 beats) for that. FYI Drutam is two beats.

Answer (score 1):

Misra Jhampa in Karnataka Sangeet and Yakshagana is the equivalent of Jhaap Taal in Hindustani. 7 akshara laghu, anudruta and dhruta (7+1+2). This is still played correctly as misra-jhampa in Yakshagana. Khanda Chapu resembles Tvarita Jhampa and is sort of half of Jhampa and is easy to learn and play but technically incorrect. When I say Khanda Chapu is technically incorrect it means, Khanda chapu will not match the actual rhythmical phrases of literature in compositions. So Misra Jhampa in Karnataka Sangeet and Yakshagana is the equivalent of Jhaap Taal in Hindustani.